# Inserting a node at the end of a singly linked list in C

Tags: c

I don't know where I made a mistake. The program is compiling successfully but then in the output I get a segmentation fault when I try to insert more than 1 number.The first number gets inserted.

Someone please help me out!!
Tell me where I went wrong.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next; 
};

struct node* head;


void insert(int num){
    struct node* temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data = num;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL){
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }
    struct node* temp2 = head;
    while(temp2!=NULL){
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    temp2->next = temp1;
}

void print(){
    struct node* temp = head;
    printf("The list is \n");
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    void insert(int num);
    void print();
    head = NULL;
    int x,n,i;
    printf("Enter the limit: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insert(x);
        print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void insert(int num);
    void print();` move declarations outside block scope of `main()`.

Comment: Time to learn how to *debug* your programs. From "printf" debugging to [rubber duck debugging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to using an actual debugger to catch crashes or step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct node* temp1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`  1) the returned type from `malloc()`, in C, is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.   2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );`  to output both you error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `void print();`  1) this prototype should be at/near the top of the file.  2) when prototyping  a function that takes no parameters, always include `void` between the parens,  Otherwise the compiler produces code that will accept any number of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You have the while loop in insert... in that loop you do

```
while(temp2!=NULL)
```

so the loop terminates when

```
temp2 = NULL
```

then in the next line you say

```
temp2->next = temp1
```

that’s why you get the segfault, because you are dereferencing NULL pointer.

Instead make the while loop condition be

```
while(temp2->next != NULL)
```

head is not NULL since you already check for that condition previously.

Answer (score 0):

One of suggestion I have is

There are two types you can write functions. You can direct define the function with whole body like you did here. But for that you must be sure that the function is not called before the definition.

The other way which is good one also (in my opinion) to declare the function at start and then define it later. In that way you can call the function before definition also.

In you case declare these two

```
void insert(int num);
void print();
```

functions at the start (before defination) and outside of the `main()`

Answer (score 0):

```
temp2->next = temp1;
```

You are getting a segmentation fault because of this. `temp2` is null and code is trying to access `next` in it.

To add the node at the end of the list you need to hold the pointer of the last node. In your case, you are holding `NULL` in `temp2`. Change the `while` loop condition to `temp2->next != NULL`.

Suggestion: It is always good to print values while you iterate through the list. Like you have done in your `print()` function. This always helps in debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

in function: insert()

this loop:

```
while(temp2!=NULL)
```

results in `temp2` containing NULL when the loop exits.  Suggest:

```
while( temp2->next != NULL )
```

so when the loop exits, `temp2` is pointing to the last 'node' in the linked list